# How to check whether a Variable=AnotherVariable+1 in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to have a conditional expression as below in Prolog and the test it.

```
checkNum(X,Y,helloWorld):- X=Y+1.
```

But when I test **checkNum(7,6,Z)** it says No! I think this condition is true but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X=Y+1` tries to unify variable `X` with term `Y+1`.

As you are passing `7` and `6` to your procedure, it tries to unify `7` with the term `6+1` which are not equal.

What you want is to evaluate the right side of the expression (`Y+1`) and see if it equals `X`.
To do that you have to use `is/2`.

So, you should use `X is Y+1`

Comment: Still doesn't work and returns "No" when I ask : checkNum(7,6,Z)

Comment: Have you reconsulted your source ?. This procedure should work just fine: `checkNum(X, Y, helloWorld):- X is Y+1.` when called with `checkNum(7,6,Z).`